# SwiperJS move more than just one slide on click

Tags: javascript, angular, swiper.js

I want to implement the feature, when I click arrow it moves 3 or 4 slides to the right or to the left, not just one slide.

I am working with Angular

Feature, when it moves one slide works, but I can't get moving more than just one slide to work.

Here is code for moving just one slide to the right or to the left

```
  scrollLeft() {
    this.swiper!.swiperRef.slidePrev(500);
    this.scrollArrows();
  }

  scrollRight() {
    this.swiper!.swiperRef.slideNext(500);
    this.scrollArrows();
  }
```

Config:

```
  swiperConfig: any = {
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    loop: true,
    spaceBetween: 20,
    autoplay: {
      delay: 1000,
      disableOnInteraction: false,
    },
  };
```

Thanks for everyone to help.

Comment: The `slidePrev` and `slideNext` methods do exactly what their names say. You will probably have to use `slideTo` instead, and calculate the necessary slide index yourself.

Comment: have you tried changing `slidesPerView`?

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I implemented slideTo and it works great.  Thank you.